# How to use Json string in javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function

```
 var url = "MyAvailability.aspx?mode=get";

        $.get(url,
        function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

that returns a Json string representation

```
events: [{'id': 1,'start': new Date(year, month, day, 12),'end': new Date(year, month, day, 13, 30),'title': 'Lunch with Mike'},{'id': 2,'start': new Date(year, month, day, 14),'end': new Date(year, month, day, 14, 45),'title': 'Dev Meeting'},{'id': 3,'start': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 17),'end': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 17, 45),'title': 'Hair cut'},{'id': 4,'start': new Date(year, month, day - 1, 8),'end': new Date(year, month, day - 1, 9, 30),'title': 'Team breakfast'},{'id': 5,'start': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 14),'end': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 15),'title': 'Product showcase'},{'id': 6,'start': new Date(year, month, day, 10),'end': new Date(year, month, day, 11),'title': 'I'm read-only',readOnly: true'}]';

If i do alert(data);
```

it works but if i am trying to assign the data to a variable it fails.

my aim is to return from the function something like

```
 return {
        events: [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "start": new Date(year, month, day, 12),
            "end": new Date(year, month, day, 13, 30),
            "title": "Lunch with Mike"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "start": new Date(year, month, day, 14),
            "end": new Date(year, month, day, 14, 45),
            "title": "Dev Meeting"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "start": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 17),
            "end": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 17, 45),
            "title": "Hair cut"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "start": new Date(year, month, day - 1, 8),
            "end": new Date(year, month, day - 1, 9, 30),
            "title": "Team breakfast"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "start": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 14),
            "end": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 15),
            "title": "Product showcase"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "start": new Date(year, month, day, 10),
            "end": new Date(year, month, day, 11),
            "title": "I'm read-only",
            readOnly: true
        }
    ]
    };
```

but i am not able to

if i do return data doesn t work

could you help me please i am getting crazy on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you miss specification of a data format in your .get call.
Please try this one:

```
$.get(url,
function(data) {
    alert(data);
},"json");
```

or consider using `.getJSON` method from a jquery

Comment: When I use the above function the function(data) is skipped. Do i have to import any library to  use Json?

Comment: What does it mean function is skipped? Do you get javascript errors?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't too clear, just saying "it fails" or "it doesn't work" doesn't help much.  However, if you're returning a json response to the browser, you should:

1. Use the `$.getJSON` method, instead of `$.get`, OR
2. Set the datatype of your `$.get` request to "json".

If you don't do either of these things, you'll need to manually parse the returned string into an object by doing:

```
var myObj = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

where the data variable holds the returned json string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the `return` statement, really, but with the fact that the function it's in is called *asynchronously*. Thus if you put your `$.get()` call in a function, then that function will return *before* that callback function is invoked.

Instead of working with a return value, have the function itself do the work (or call some other function to do the work).